# Missing FORGE_CLIENT_ID or FORGE_CLIENT_SECRET env. variables

Tags: autodesk-forge

[It shows:Missing FORGE_CLIENT_ID or FORGE_CLIENT_SECRET env. variables](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lPDIU.png)

I followed the node.js tutorial step by step, and finally the test showed that the ID and password were null values.I ended up writing the ID and password directly into config.js, and the project barely got going.

Comment: Welcome at stack**overflow**. (I find SE questions work best with an explicit question at the end of the question post - what *is* yours? See [How do I ask a Good Question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest way is to add an `env` attribute in your `.vscode/launch.json` like the below. Note. Client Id and Secret are not your developer id and password. Please refer to the [OAuth create an app tutorial - Step 3: Note Down Your Client ID and Secret](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/oauth/v2/tutorials/create-app/#step-3-note-down-your-client-id-and-secret) to see your Client Id and Secret are.

```
{
    // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
    // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
    // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "type": "node",
            "request": "launch",
            "name": "Launch Program",
            "skipFiles": [
                "<node_internals>/**"
            ],
            "program": "${workspaceFolder}/start.js",
            "env": {
                "FORGE_CLIENT_ID": "",
                "FORGE_CLIENT_SECRET": "",
                "FORGE_CALLBACK_URL": "http://localhost:3000/api/forge/callback/oauth"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Ah, sorry for the typo -> Client

Comment: thank you!I solved my problem，And I found that I could write the user name and password directly to config.js